# How to convert a $3\times 5$ matrix to a product of a $3\times 2$ and $2\times 5$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I have a matrix 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{bmatrix},$$
 and I would like to write this as a product of a $3\times 2$ and $2\times 5$ matrix.

By reducing the matrix to row echelon form I get the $2\times 5$ matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$
How do I get the $3\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: Hint : The first row is the sum of the two other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization):

> In practice, we can construct one specific rank factorization $A = CF$ as follows: we can compute $B$, the reduced row echelon form of $A$. Then 
>   $C$ is obtained by removing from $A$ all non-pivot columns, and 
>   $F$ by eliminating all zero rows of $B$.

In your case, $A$ has rank 2, and you already computed the reduced row echelon form without the zero rows as 
$$
F = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$C$ is obtained by picking only the pivot-columns (one and two) from $A$
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0\\
 0 & 1\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and $A=CF$ is the desired decomposition.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would I need to compute the column echelon form to find that the first two columns are the pivot columns?

Comment: @user152103: No. That are the pivot indices used to compute the reduced  row echelon form.

Answer (score 0):

Each row of the $3×2$ matrix represents coefficients for a linear combination of the rows of the $2×5$ matrix that produces a row of the original matrix.

Using the found row-echelon form, let's consider the first row of the $3×2$ matrix:
$$(1,1,2,2,3)=a(1,0,1,2,2)+b(0,1,1,0,1)$$
We see that $a=b=1$, so the first row is $(1,1)$. Similar computations apply for the other two rows.